# Adding content to silver light controls from database using wcf ria services

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to retrieve strings from the database and add it as content to the controls on my page before it loads(somewhat like a custom localization). I retrieve my strings from the database uing ria services as follows:

**

```
 Web.DomainService1 context = new Web.DomainService1();

LoadOperation<Web.LocalizationTab>LoadOp=context.Load(context.GetLocalizationTabsQuery(currentCulture, moduleName));

 Dictionary<string, string> localizationDictonary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        List<Web.LocalizationTab> localList = new List<Web.LocalizationTab>();

        LoadOp.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            localList = LoadOp.Entities.ToList<Web.LocalizationTab>();

            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(localList.Count.ToString());
            foreach (Web.LocalizationTab item in localList)
            {
                // var control = this.FindName(item.Control_ID.ToString());
                if (!localizationDictonary.ContainsKey(item.Control_ID))
                {
                    localizationDictonary.Add(item.Control_ID, item.Control_Text);
                }
            }

        };**
```

This piece of code is in a separate class called utilities.cs.
now in my Mainpage.xaml.cs i need to get this dictionary with values and then set the controls with the strings from the dictionary. 
my problem is that when i do the following in the constructor of Mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
utilities.getDict(ModuleName);

button1.Content = localizationDictonary["button1"].ToString();
```

i get an exception as the dictionary doesnt contain values at that point of time.. The load completed event of getting data from the database gets fired only after my constructor is exited. now how do i go about setting my controls automatically in this particular scenario??

Answer (score 1):

Try loading your dictionary in the Silverlight Application class [StartUp event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This should ensure that your Dictionary is loaded (and could be placed in the Application Resources for retrieval elsewhere in your application).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait for the GetLocalizationTabsQuery to complete before instantiating your MainPage. In your App.xaml.cs file, you can start the query, add a query completed handler, and only create the MainPage when the query completed handler gets called.